# What is the Firebase Auth Session Cookie JWK URL?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, jwk, google-cloud-identity

With a regular Firebase auth ID token we can verify using the JWK URL of https://www.googleapis.com/service_accounts/v1/jwk/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com

If you make a [Session Cookie](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies) instead, where the issuer is https://session.firebase.google.com/, what URL is the JWK located at?

Answer (score 1):

The public certificates are here:

https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/publicKeys

Each certificate is in PEM format. Extract the public key from the certificate and verify the signature after validating the JWT header and payload. The JWT header **kid** will tell you which certificate to use.

Google provides an API that you can call to fetch the JWK for a session cookie:

[Method: getSessionCookiePublicKeys](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v1/TopLevel/getSessionCookiePublicKeys)

Comment: Thank you friend but I was hoping something was available in JWK form, I am using it with Hasura's JWT auth mode https://hasura.io/docs/latest/graphql/core/auth/authentication/jwt.html

Comment: @ArjunYelamanchili You can convert one format to the other. A public certificate is two prime numbers - n and e with extra wrapping. A JWK is two same two numbers plus descriptors. The important information is the same. To verify a signature, you only need the two prime numbers. Public certificates, public keys, and JWKs are just different ways of encoding the two prime numbers.

Comment: @ArjunYelamanchili - Your library supports public certificates. **You can also provide the key (certificate, PEM encoded public key) as a string - in the key field along with the type.**